# Adding a css class in a dynamically created handlebars template

Tags: css, templates, handlebars.js

I have a JSON object that I am looping through to dynamically create x amount of ULs then LIs. I need to create two `{{#each}}` to create the content. However when I add a CSS class to my handlebars template it does not come through onto the UL as it does in the second `{{#each}}` - how do I stop this? Here is the template:

```
<div class="{{panel-container__Css-class}} {{panel-menu__Css-class}}" data-component="panel">
  {{#each sections}}
  <ul id="{{id}}" class="{{panel-menu__Css-class}}">
    {{#each list}}
    <li><a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Here is what i am passing in:

```
    <nav data-component="navigation">
        {{> nav-dropdown menu-button__Css-class="menu-button" menu-button__Css-class-nav="panel"  target-id="panel-nav"  }}
        {{> nav-dropdown menu-button__Css-class="region-button" menu-button__Css-class-nav="region" target-id="panel-region" menu-button__copy=panel.copy}}
        {{!--var links = [{"title": "Test","url": "/"}];--}}
        {{> panel panel-menu__Css-class="navigation__menu-styles" panel-container__Css-class="navigation__menu-container" sections=navigation.sections links=navigation.sections.list  }}
    </nav>
```

Comment: An ID must be unique. Use a class when you have multiple ul elements.

Comment: The id is unique because there may be multiple UL's within the nav - which hide and show content depending on what button was pressed @Gerard

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the [Handlebars path](http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths) that will allow you to obtain the value of `panel-menu__Css-class` from within `{{#each sections}}`. You need to understand that when you are within `{{#each sections}}`, your `this` context is the currently iterated element of the `sections` array. You must step  up a level to the parent context which has the `panel-menu__Css-class` property you are trying to access:

```
<ul id="{{id}}" class="{{../panel-menu__Css-class}}">
```